# gradient filled image print in grayscale

Tags: objective-c, macos

i am drawing an image with gradient fill.

```
Printing_View* my_print_view =[[Printing_View alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

NSPrintOperation* printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:my_print_view printInfo:pass_info];

 [printOperation setCanSpawnSeparateThread:YES];
        [printOperation setShowsPrintPanel:NO];

[printOperation runOperationModalForWindow:window delegate:window didRunSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];

and draw image in draw rect of my view class

[drawing_image drawInRect:drawing_rect
                             fromRect:NSZeroRect
                            operation:NSCompositeCopy
                             fraction:1.0];
```

it looks ok in preview but when i print this image the image print in greyscale i really don't understand what happens.

please help me.

Comment: Try `setShowsPrintPanel:YES` and check if a a grayscale printer option is switched on.

Comment: i chk it grayscale option is not selected, if there is any solid colour on image than its prints gradient properly.